# Chrome extension - call function defined on tab (Reference error)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm opening a tab and trying to call a function defined in it but i always get a "reference error". I send a message to the script after the script is loaded asking to run "test1" function located on the tab code.

Here is my code:

**Extention code**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "script.js", runAt: "document_end"}, function(array){  
    //send message executeTest to the created tab
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {msg: "executeTest"});
});
```

**script.js**

```
url = document.URL; 
window.addEventListener("load", doStuff, true);

function doStuff(){

    //listen for messages coming from extension
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(message, sender) {

            var msg = message.msg;
            var url = message.url;    

            switch(msg){
                case "executeTest":
                    test1();
                break;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

**Tab HTML**

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Tab Javascript**

```
function test1(){
    console.log("test1 is running!");
}
```

I receive the message on the script but it's not possible to execute "test1()".

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Please do not "edit away" the problem in a way that answers become irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of unrelated issues here.

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {msg: executeTest});
```

`executeTest` is not a string, it's an (undefined) identifier. That's what throwing the error.

Correct way (ninja'd by user2570380) is to write

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {msg: "executeTest"});
```

---

The other problem is that you **will not be able to call** `test1()`, because content scripts [live in isolated context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment).

To bypass it, you either need to employ [messaging between the webpage and your extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication), use [`externally_connectable`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage), or [inject some of your code into the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/934239) to trigger what you need.

Considering that you do not control the webpage, you need to inject code in the page's context. Example:

control.js

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // We only accept messages from ourselves
  if (event.source != window)
    return;

  if (event.data.source && (event.data.source == "MyExtension")) {
    switch(event.data.command){
      case "test1":
        test1();
        break;
    }
  }
}, false);
```

script.js

```
// Initialization
var s = document.createElement('script');
// TODO: add "control.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('control.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

// Sending a command (make sure script initialized listener first)
window.postMessage({ source: "MyExtension", command: "test1" }, "*");
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. If you're referring to injecting into the page's context, you can do it with methods described in the last link, from within `script.js`. You can simply inject `test1();` in a script tag.

Comment: I want to run test1() from the tab code (external code opened in a tab).

Comment: Then what I said above is correct. You can inject code consisting of calling `test1()` with the method I linked to; doing so from the context of `script.js` will inject it in the page's context, where `test1` is defined.

Comment: Okay. I was doing it from the background page. Should i define "script.js" as a content script or there is no need ? Or can I simply use it by calling "executeScript" ?

Comment: There is no need; what you inject with `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is considered a content script.

Comment: _It's BAD to have such discussions in comments here, but you don't have enough reputation for a chatroom._ This won't work because `test1()` is a ReferenceError, and in any case your `InjectFunc` expects a function _reference_, which would be `test1`. But that again wouldn't work: there is NO `test1` in script.js. See my edited answer for a more flexible solution using messaging.

Comment: I finally get it right ! I was having synchronization problems... Thanks for your help and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {msg: "executeTest"});`

Quotes.

Comment: That was a typo ! Sorry ^^ I'm able to receive the message as i said but when "test1()" is called i get a reference error.